# ajax datatable export buttons not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

friends, I am able to load data from ajax to data table but export buttons not working when I click on export buttons only headings are shown please help me to sort this here is my code

```
 <div class="box-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Target</th>
                <th>Orders</th>
                <th>Sale</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody">

        </tbody>

    </table>


<script>
//Load Data in Table when documents is ready
 $(document).ready(function () {
loadData();
    });

    //Load Data function
    function loadData() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/List",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(result, function (key, item) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Party_target + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Party_order + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Party_sale + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        });

        $('#example1').html(html);
                },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
});
 }
    </script>
```

[image: data table data]

here is exported excel file
[image: exported excel file]

sorry I forget to show export script here is the export code I use this on my master page

```
   <script>
     `   $(function () {

var example1 =  $("#example1").DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      buttons: ['excelHtml5',
         {
             extend: 'pdfHtml5',
             title: "*",
             download: 'open'
         },
          {
              extend: 'print',
              autoPrint: true,
              customize: function (win) {
                  $(win.document.body)
                      .css('font-size', '10pt');

                  $(win.document.body).find('table')
                      .addClass('compact')
                      .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                  var medias = win.document.querySelectorAll('[media="screen"]');
                  for (var i = 0; i < medias.length; i++) { medias.item(i).media = "all" };
              }
          },
   { extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    title: 'Document Tittle',
    customize: function (doc) {
        if (doc) {
            for (var i = 1; i < doc.content[1].table.body.length; i++) {

                var tmptext = doc.content[1].table.body[i][0].text;
                tmptext = tmptext.substring(10, tmptext.indexOf("width=") - 2);

                doc.content[1].table.body[i][0] = {
                    margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                    alignment: 'center',
                    image: tmptext,
                    width: 60,
                    height: 58
                };
            }
        }
    },
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        stripHtml: false
    }
}
      ]

});

example1.buttons().container().appendTo($('.col-sm-6:eq(0)', example1.table().container()));

  });
  </script>`
```

Comment: please post code of exporting

Comment: @ManuVarghese sorry i forget to show export script i update my question now please check